# Pandas: what are "string function names" called technically?

Tags: pandas

When using pandas you can in certain cases pass names of functions as strings instead of actual references to those functions. For example: `df.transform('round')`.

In the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) they call these "string function names" but is there another (perhaps more technical) name for these kinds of strings?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Pandas doesn't really *want* to do this, it's just that in some cases i.e. when using some functions like `mean` it's required to put the quotes, otherwise errors would be called.

With cases like `round` quotes wouldn't be actually needed, since they're already builtin functions. The "function names" are really just sort of a way to represent these function names so that they don't get mixed up with other functions.

As mentioned in the documentation link you provided, they call it:

> string function name

There is really no special turn IMO.

Comment: Can you share the logic of the implementation?

Comment: It seems like you're saying `mean` is in some way a "reserved word" (like `if` and `def` are). Are you saying that? Because `mean` is not a Python reserved word and I don't think a library (like Pandas) can introduce reserved words, right?

Comment: I'll update the question to say "string function name".

Comment: @NielsBom Sorry I mean like `mean` is an pandas function

Answer (score 1):

By passing an invalid string to the `aggregate` method (ex. `df.agg('max2')`) and following the Traceback I got to the following code (pandas version 1.1.4):

```py
class SelectionMixin:
    """
    mixin implementing the selection & aggregation interface on a group-like
    object sub-classes need to define: obj, exclusions
    """

# < some lines deleted >

    def _try_aggregate_string_function(self, arg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        if arg is a string, then try to operate on it:
        - try to find a function (or attribute) on ourselves
        - try to find a numpy function
        - raise
        """
        assert isinstance(arg, str)

        f = getattr(self, arg, None)
        if f is not None:
            if callable(f):
                return f(*args, **kwargs)

            # people may try to aggregate on a non-callable attribute
            # but don't let them think they can pass args to it
            assert len(args) == 0
            assert len([kwarg for kwarg in kwargs if kwarg not in ["axis"]]) == 0
            return f

        f = getattr(np, arg, None)
        if f is not None:
            if hasattr(self, "__array__"):
                # in particular exclude Window
                return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

        raise AttributeError(
            f"'{arg}' is not a valid function for '{type(self).__name__}' object"
        )
```

It seems that we fall into this code whenever we pass a string function name to `aggregate`.  If we were to look into the familiar pandas objects (Series, DataFrame, GroupBy) we would find that they inherit from `SelectionMixin`.

The string function names are looked up either in the pandas object itself (`getattr(self, arg, None)`) or in Numpy (`getattr(np, arg, None)`).  So the string function names simply represent attributes of some object, either methods of a pandas object or functions defined in Numpy.